# Using a Button under the context:SecondActivity in a recyclerView

Tags: android

For example:
This is my Button in `SecondActivity.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/Increase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:text="Increase"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to call this button in a `FragmentClass` but whenever I do the app crashes.

```
Increase= (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Increase)
```

How do I use the button in other fragment class? Much appreciate

Comment: show your code with error log

Comment: You get a null pointer exception right?

Comment: you can't inflate a button from activity layout in the fragment class. but tell us what you want to achieve with that?

Comment: you should pass button context of that activity  in next class and use... pass the button through construtor

Comment: Thanks guys. The solution provided by Bogdan Lonchuk works! Much Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use getActivity() method.

Use this snippet with your fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_select, container, false);
      yourButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn);
}
```

In that case you will be able to use the button from Activity in your Fragment.